# using properties from root level to inner jar

Tags: java, spring

Composite spring app (war) contains root context and in /lib folder several jar have context too.
I have a root props file. 
In root context properties resolves fine. But in inner jars props are not resolved. When I place properties in the inner jar all resolved.
App server is weblogic. But when I tested localy at jetty
All works fine with this conf:

Comment: How you're loading/accesing those props? ([Consider using manifest for parametrization][1])


  [1]: http://manifests.jcabi.com/

Comment: Sorry. I forgot. Local at jetty all works fine. But at weblogic it's could not resolved. I use <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:**foo.properties" />